# use a class instead of id in a link

Tags: html

Is it possible to make a link that would normally go to an id:

`<a href="http://example.com/page#someid">`

instead go to a class:

`<a href="http://example.com/page.someclass">`

Would the page scroll wildly up and down, trying to reach all the elements with that class, or would it just do nothing?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, it certainly doesn't happen in the way that you've described. What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It would do nothing, except look for a file called "page.someclass" at the server and most probably yield a 404. Please refer to the [URL spec](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/) because you're wildly confusing CSS selectors with the 'hash' part of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just try it?

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/marianrick/1xL8wcq1/)

If you are using a `class` als anchor link, your browser tries to open it as url, like in the example named above `index.content`. Because he is not able to find it, you will receive an 404 not found or 403 forbidden error.

Comment: why a 403? a 404, sure, but why a 403?

Comment: Depends on the server configuration. If the server has a very strict file system and blocks every access, thats not wanted, or has a lot of content, that is dynamically generated (~ the url could possibly exist, but is until now not requested by this user) this will result in a 403 error I guess!